# Image scaling or DOM duplicating algorithm in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom, mathematical-optimization

*Original question*:
**How do I scale an image in JavaScript without CSS support?**

My team has an STB environment, kind of an EPG thing, that supports JavaScript and DOM thrown to it. CSS support exists but we can't inject our own CSS there. The unit of measurement is always fixed and cannot be scaled  by CSS therefore.

We are showing images in the following way:

1. Every image is shown as a chunk of small images generated from the
   device
2. For a `40 x 30` image, it gives us `1200` chunks of `1px x 1px`,
   represented as DOM elements.
3. They are placed in `width x height` columns and rows, inside a parent DOM element. They look bigger on a huge screen with big physical pixel size.

Look at the image below - something I tried in **browser** for clarity:

[image: Pixel representation]

Assume that every block above is an image in itself of 1 x 1 pixels, hence a DOM element. Collectively there are always 40 x 30 = 1200 DOM elements at one time.

We want to scale this in a function call, to double its size. Or at least add 10 units to both width and height.

What logic do I write in JavaScript? Do I duplicate every DOM element and place the duplicate next to original? That only doubles the width. Do I multiply 4 times for height too?
Help appreciated.

**UPDATE**:
From the only answer, it seems what I need is to implement a scaling or duplicating algorithm in JavaScript.

When we zoom images in any OS, what algorithm do they apply to every pixel to double its size and display 1 pixel by 4 hardware pixels?

I need to do the same thing to DOM elements, where every `span` or `img` element acts as a pixel.

Comment: Yes I think doubling those elements both horizontally and vertically is the only way to go. I might be mistaking though..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see you're limited to two options:

- Either double the size of the individual dom-pixels
- Or if this is not possible, scale your pixelmap over twice the number of dom-pixels (so add every pixel twice and copy each row at the end)

Of course the first option is by far the most efficient one, but it seems the environment you're working in is quite restrictive, so I assume this is not possible.

Comment: Assuming that I double the no. of DOM elements, how do I place them, and the next element? I have to duplicate the first `img` and place it in place of second `img`. Then the original second `img` in place of 3rd and fourth. Then the fourth `img` and so on...
This is a very intensive operation. What's the efficient way?

Comment: If you already have a full map then I think the most efficient way is saying `l = row[x].lenght` and looping from `l to 0` moving `row[x][l*2] = row[x][l];row[x][l*2-1] = row[x][l]` in each loop. Then once you finish just actually do the same for the rows rather than the cells. At least, that's assuming it's a normal array structure and not some odd object or bytearrays.

Comment: I need to do the same in 2 dimensions, separately for column element per row. Complexity will be more than `n^2`. Anything less than that

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use Images only, not pixels, the function is readyly available,

use this [link](http://techslides.com/javascript-image-resizer-and-scaling-algorithms/)

this provides best image interpolation without any problem,

If you want to do it manually,

then double it in row and then in column, means first horizontally, then vertically double,

Example(3x3)

```
XCV
DFG
ERT
```

it will become this in first row-pix multiplier

```
XXCCVV
DDFFGG
EERRTT
```

then column-pix multiplier

```
XXCCVV
XXCCVV
DDFFGG
XXCCVV
EERRTT
XXCCVV
```

Here you can just insert duplicate row below each row,
the same you can apply in the first step, if you are creating matrix then it will help you multiplying each..

I hope this will help..

Comment: +1. Thanks. I checked all the links that were available on your post, from which only the ones with algorithm were useful. Rest used the native software functionality like doubling canvas size and using the canvas do stuff. I am accepting the original first answer.

Comment: FYI, Perhaps the second option of selected answer will not work well, as it will show the image like one stretched image and another same below the same.. I hope this will help..

Comment: The unit is one pixel (or block) which cannot be further dissected. So if we double all the units horizontally, and then duplicate this horizontal row, it should theoretically work. That seemed logical to me!

Comment: Thank you :), Its basic of C Graphics, but the best is hq3 but I don't know how you will be able to implement, FYI link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_scaling#hqnx_family